# Sefira Restrictions During Chol Hamoed Pesach

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, chol-hamoed, music, minhag

For those who hold sefira from the first day until the thirty-third, are the restrictions in effect during chol hamoed? While you are not allowed to cut your hair even during chol hamoed Succos, can one listen to music during chol hamoed?

Comment: Several years ago, my local rabbi said it is muttar to listen to music during chol hamoed pesach (even for those who do first half of sefira), but I can't remember the source he brought, so I won't post as an answer.

Comment: You're question also applies to shaving for [those who shave on chol hamoed](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11518/759).

Comment: ...and also to getting remarried on Chol haMoed.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37082

Comment: Chabad allows it, according to the opinions I've heard.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/273

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per Az Nidbru 10:23:2 as well as Yechave Daas 1:45 it is permissible to listen to music on Chol Hamoed Pesach.

Answer (score 3):

[*Aruch Hashulchan* 493:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A6.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93) cites, if I'm reading him right, "various customs about [the restrictions of these days]. Some have practiced a prohibition **from immediately after *Pesach*** until the 33d of the *omer* and from then on weddings and haircuts are permitted, because a *midrash* has it that fifteen days before *Shavuos* [the students of *Rabi Akiva*] stopped dying, so that 34 days are left; it would have been logical to practice the prohibition until the 35th of the count, but we say part of the day is like its whole, so [these things are] permitted on the day of the 34th and not earlier.... [And others keep the second 'half'.]" (Emphasis added.)

As always, for a matter of practical *halacha*, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 2):

My local orthodox rabbi said you're allowed to listen to music during Choel Hamoed

Comment: Mike, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this answer! You could make it much more valuable by [edit]ing in more information about who your rabbi is, what tradition he subscribes to, and any sources or reasoning he may have cited. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 1):

[Pri Megadim (Mishbitzos Zahav) Siman 493 S"K 2](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2439) writes based on the Magen Avraham that one should stop already by Chol Hamoed: "ריקודן ומחולות יש לאסור בחול המועד פסח"

Comment: You left out part of the phrase. He says ריקודן ומחולות של רשות יש לאסור but if done for mitzva, such as to celebrate the holiday, they are permitted. Indeed if you aren't turning on the music for the purpose of enjoying the holiday then you can't do it anyway on Chol Hamoed because it's a melacha.

Comment: That is not the reason he gives to asur it.

Comment: I don't understand your response.