# Is one allowed to listen to music during Pesach?

Tags: minhag, sefirat-ha-omer, mourning-aveilus, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sefira Restrictions During Chol Hamoed Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/sefira-restrictions-during-chol-hamoed-pesach)

One of the reasons given to pushing off the Aveilus period until after Rosh Chodesh Iyar is because one should avoid mourning during Nissan.

Yet, many keep either the full Omer as a time of mourning, or at least the first 33 days (until lag baomer).

Do they also keep mourning (not listening to music, etc.) during Chol Hamoed (where halachically one is not allowed to mourn even for close relatives) or not?

Comment: You're question also applies to shaving for [those who shave on chol hamoed](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11518/759).